# How to delete observations in SAS

Tags: sas

I'm working in SAS with a file with roughly 80000 observations, I've decided to keep 11 variables.

I want to delete variables with a value exceeding 97. These are missing observations and I don't want to deal with that.

I tried using the followin code (please don't judge):

```
  199  DATA radata;
200       SET radata;
201       IF ca10 <= 97 THEN OUTPUT;
202       IF ca10 > 97 THEN DELETE;
203  IF sex <= 97 THEN OUTPUT;
204       IF sex > 97 THEN DELETE;
205       IF sex <= 97 THEN OUTPUT;
206       IF sex > 97 THEN DELETE;
207       IF cityrur <= 97 THEN OUTPUT;
208       IF cityrur > 97 THEN DELETE;
209       IF edu3 <= 97 THEN OUTPUT;
210       IF edu3 > 97 THEN DELETE;
211       IF ca10 <= 97 THEN OUTPUT;
212       IF ca10 > 97 THEN DELETE;
213       IF hinc3rel <= 97 THEN OUTPUT;
214       IF hinc3rel > 97 THEN DELETE;
215       IF aa10i <= 97 THEN OUTPUT;
216       IF aa10i > 97 THEN DELETE;
217       IF ba10 <= 97 THEN OUTPUT;
218       IF ba10 > 97 THEN DELETE;
219       IF age <= 97 THEN OUTPUT;
220       IF age > 97 THEN DELETE;
221       IF ga10c <= 97 THEN OUTPUT;
222       IF ga10c > 97 THEN DELETE;
223       IF bc20 <= 97 THEN OUTPUT;
224       IF bc20 > 97 THEN DELETE;
225       IF ac10a <= 97 THEN OUTPUT;
226       IF ac10a > 97 THEN DELETE;
227       IF ga10j <= 97 THEN OUTPUT;
228       IF ga10j > 97 THEN DELETE;
229    RUN;
```

SAS however, responds not by subtracting observations but by **adding more of them!**

Please help.....

Comment: Please could you post an example of what your input dataset looks like and the corresponding output data you are trying to produce?

Comment: Do you want to remove all rows where one or more of the variables are > 97 ? Or all rows where all the variables are > 97 ? Or all columns where all values are > 97 ?  The unjudged code is a mishmash, the output will have a row repeated for every value <= 97 up to the first case of a value > 97.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://communities.sas.com/ is probably a better place to ask such a programming question (and I wouldn't be surprised if this question is closed).

Here are 3 ways to delete all observations (i.e., rows) with at least one value of those variables being greater than 97:

```
data radata;
  set radata;
  array x(10) ca10 sex cityrur edu3 hinc3 aa10i age ga10c bc20 ga10j;
  do i=1 to 10; 
     if x(i) > 97 then delete;
  end;
run;
```

or

```
data radata;
  set radata;
  if ca10 > 97 then delete;
  if sex > 97 then delete; 
  if cityrur > 97 then delete;
  if edu3 > 97 then delete;
  if hinc3 > 97 then delete;
  if aa10i > 97 then delete;
  if age > 97 then delete;
  if ga10c > 97 then delete;
  if bc20 > 97 then delete;
  if ga10j > 97 then delete;
run;
```

or

```
data radata;
  set radata;
  if ca10 > 97 or sex > 97 or cityrur > 97 or edu3 > 97 or
     hinc3 > 97 or aa10i > 97 or age > 97 or ga10c > 97 or
     bc20 > 97 or ga10j > 97 then delete;
run;
```

Now if you just want those variables to have the missing value symbol (`.`) and not delete the whole observation, then you'll need to replace `delete` with `x(i) = .`.  You can do something similar for the second example.